# How to tell prolog if the function returns false then skip it?(15 puzzle game)

Tags: prolog

I have made a function which in it I call several functions, but when one of them returns false  the main function stops and returns false. So is there a way to tell Prolog if the function returns false then skip it and check the rest?

In detail: I am trying to make the 15 puzzle game as a project,
and I want to make function that gives me all the possible next moves.

I end up with calling all the previous functions that controls the blank tile.

```
next_move(Board, Moves):-
  swapup(Board,Result),
  swapdown(Board,Result),
  swapright(Board,Result),
  swapleft(Board,Result).
```

I want this function to return all the next possible moves

Here is the full code:

```
position([Tile|_], Tile, 0).
position([_|Tail], Tile, Index):-
  position(Tail, Tile, Index1),
  Index is Index1+1.

swap(Board,I,J,R) :-
   same_length(Board,R),
   append(BeforeI,[AtI|PastI],Board),
   append(BeforeI,[AtJ|PastI],Bs),
   append(BeforeJ,[AtJ|PastJ],Bs),
   append(BeforeJ,[AtI|PastJ],R),
   length(BeforeI,I),
   length(BeforeJ,J).

swapup(Board,Result):-
    position(Board,0,Index),
    Index \=0,
    Index \=1,
    Index \=2,
    Index \=3,
    Up is Index-4,
    swap(Board,Up,Index,Result).

swapdown(Board,Result):-
    position([],0,Index),
    Index \=12,
    Index \=13,
    Index \=14,
    Index \=15,
    Down is Index+4,
    swap(Board, Down, Index, Result).

swapright(Board,Result):-
    position([],0,Index),
    Index \=3,
    Index \=7,
    Index \=11,
    Index \=15,
    Right is Index+1,
    swap(Board, Right, Index, Result).

swapleft(Board,Result):-
    position([],0,Index),
    Index \=0,
    Index \=4,
    Index \=8,
    Index \=12,
    Left is Index-1,
    swap(Board, Left, Index, Result).

swap(Board,Result) :- swapup(Board,Result).
swap(Board,Result) :- swapdown(Board,Result).
swap(Board,Result) :- swapright(Board,Result).
swap(Board,Result) :- swapleft(Board,Result).

next_move(Board,Moves) :- findall(Result,swap(Board,Result),Moves).
```

Comment: They're not functions, they are predicates. They don't return anything, they succeed or fail, and may unify variables as they go.

Comment: It would be really great if you could post your code?

Comment: I edited the post and put the code

Comment: Can you please post all of the code? I can see what's going wrong, but I can't suggest exactly how to fix it without all of the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to comment on the code you've given so far. Please note the difference in the type of answer I can give when you give code in your question.

Comment: I edited the post with the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple program:

```
a.
b :- fail.
c.

g :- a, b, c.
```

I can ask if `g` succeeds:

```
?- g.
false.
```

It does not.

I can solve this two ways.

(1)

```
g :- a, b, c.
g :- a, c.
```

(2)

```
g :- a, (b; true), c.
```

Either way, `g` succeeds now:

```
?- g.
true.
```

---

### Update

This is the code you've posted:

```
next_move(Board, Moves) :-
    swapup(Board,Result),
    swapdown(Board,Result),
    swapright(Board,Result),
    swapleft(Board,Result).
```

On the LHS you have a variable `Moves` that is not on the RHS. `Moves` can never be unified and will always remain a variable.

Let's ignore that for a minute and look at the `swap` predicates.

If I assume that `Result` is a valid move given the current state of the `Board` then what your code is saying `next_move(Board, Moves)` succeeds when each of the `swap` predicates succeed and that can't happen unless the move you get from each of the `swap` predicates is the same.

Once `swapup(Board,Result)` succeeds it will have unified `Result` with the "swap up" move. Then you ask if `swapdown(Board,Result)` succeeds. Well, `Result` isn't a variable anymore so you're asking if the `Result` you get from `swapdown` is the same as the `Result` you get from `swapup`. I'm guessing it's not.

It's possible that you need something like this:

```
next_move(Board,[U,D,R,L]):-
    swapup(Board,U),
    swapdown(Board,D),
    swapright(Board,R),
    swapleft(Board,L).
```

But that's not clear because I don't know what value you get when your open space on your board is already at an edge.

It's probably more likely that you need this:

```
swap(Board,Result) :- swapup(Board,Result).
swap(Board,Result) :- swadown(Board,Result).
swap(Board,Result) :- swapright(Board,Result).
swap(Board,Result) :- swapleft(Board,Result).

next_move(Board,Moves) :- findall(Result,swap(Board,Result),Moves).
```

But all of this is guessing without seeing your full code.

---

Here's your code working now. There were a number of issues.

`position/3` just simply didn't work.

Here's a version that does:

```
position(List,Element,Index) :-
    position(List,Element,0,Index).

position([Element|_],Element,Index,Index).
position([_|Tail],Element,Counter,Index) :-
    Next is Counter + 1,
    position(Tail,Element,Next,Index).
```

You were always calling `swap/4` with the same order of the two indices. You have to make sure they go in in ascending order. `swap/4` didn't work in any case. Here's the new version:

```
swap(BoardIn,I,J,BoardOut) :-
    position(BoardIn,X,I), % find the value `X` at position `I`
    position(BoardIn,Y,J), % find the value `Y` at position `J`
    append(Left,[X|MiddleEnd1],BoardIn), % find the list that is `Left` of `X`
    append(Middle,[Y|End],MiddleEnd1), % find the `Middle` that is left of `Y` and the list `End` that is to the right of `Y`
    append(Middle,[X|End],MiddleEnd2), % put `X` between `Middle` and `End`.
    append(Left,[Y|MiddleEnd2],BoardOut). % put the `Y` between `Left` & `Middle`.
```

I cleaned up the `swap*/2` predicates.

```
swapup(BoardIn,BoardOut):-
    position(BoardIn,0,Index),
    Up is Index - 4,
    Up >= 0,
    swap(BoardIn,Up,Index,BoardOut).

swapdown(BoardIn,BoardOut):-
    position(BoardIn,0,Index),
    Down is Index + 4,
    Down =< 15,
    swap(BoardIn,Index,Down,BoardOut).

swapright(BoardIn,BoardOut):-
    position(BoardIn,0,Index),
    Index mod 4 =\= 3,
    Right is Index + 1,
    swap(BoardIn,Index,Right,BoardOut).

swapleft(BoardIn,BoardOut):-
    position(BoardIn,0,Index),
    Index mod 4 =\= 0,
    Left is Index - 1,
    swap(BoardIn,Left,Index,BoardOut).

swap(BoardIn,BoardOut) :- swapup(BoardIn,BoardOut).
swap(BoardIn,BoardOut) :- swapdown(BoardIn,BoardOut).
swap(BoardIn,BoardOut) :- swapright(BoardIn,BoardOut).
swap(BoardIn,BoardOut) :- swapleft(BoardIn,BoardOut).
```

And finally, here's the `next_move/2` predicate:

```
next_move(BoardIn,Moves) :-
    length(BoardIn,16),
    position(BoardIn,0,_),
    findall(BoardOut,swap(BoardIn,BoardOut),Moves).
```

Now I can call this query:

```
?- next_move([1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],Result),write(Result).
```

I get this result:

```
[[1,5,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],[1,2,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that worked but unfortunately in a wrong way, it succeeded but it returned true instead of returning any values.

Comment: well trying the first way ended up in giving me false                                                                     
                ```?- next_move([1,2,0,4,5,8],[U,D,L,R]).
false.``` ,                                                                                                                             
                            the second way it gave me an empty list                                                                          
    ```?- next_move([1,2,0,4,56,7],R).
R = [].```

Comment: @AmiraEl-Kafoury - I fixed your code. Let me know if you understand what I did.

Comment: I didn't get how the swap predicate works

Comment: @AmiraEl-Kafoury - I added some notes in `swap/4`.

Comment: one more question please, in the next_move predicate...i don't understand why did we put the Boardout as a template in findall and also in the previous swaps predicates we were giving 4 parameters but in next move we sent BoardIn and BoardOut only

Comment: @AmiraEl-Kafoury - There are two `swap` predicates `swap/2` and `swap/4`.

Comment: I understood but when I run `next_move` predicate this is what i get:   
                                                                                                            
          

```?- next_move([1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],Result),write(Result).

[]
Result = [] ```

Comment: @AmiraEl-Kafoury - When I run my code in SWI is works fine. What environment are you running in?

Comment: Same for me , I run it on SWI

Comment: but thanks to you I've understood the idea and the predicate

Comment: @AmiraEl-Kafoury - You must not have the code correct. Try copy & pasting from here: https://pastebin.com/LT5TTCwZ